# Can three elements with same id / value in a form be a problem?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

In my form I have save button that is repeated three times, saving must update data in the database such as name, surname, address, avatar etc...

All buttons work, save / update information correctly. However in the console I get a warning: [DOM] Found 3 elements with non-unique id `#save-account-details-nonce`. Can this become a problem ? Should I change the value of the save buttons?

**Button 1**

```
<!-- Save Settings -->
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;">
      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
      <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Salva modifiche', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>
```

**Button 2**

```
 <!-- Save Address -->
          <p>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Salva indirizzo', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
          </p>
```

**Button 3**

```
<!-- Upload Avatar -->
        <p style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;">
          <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
          <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload Avatar', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
        </p>
```

Comment: ID's have to be unique! Using an ID in the same page multiple times is not valid and as such it can cause a lot of problems especially on JS/jQuery basis. But since you already get a warning from your console, you should have been easily be able to self-answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should have unique `id` attributes for each element.
It will create conflict when you want to read the element via JS using `document.getElementById` or using `jQuery $('#')` or styling it using CSS

The warnings are also self-explanatory. Although it wont mess up your HTML if you just use the markup, however it will cause issues once you start manipulating the elements

Read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The `id` global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be
> unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
> when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
> (with CSS).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I am relatively new to this how could I solve? Is it enough to simply provide a different id for the three elements ?

Comment: @Snorlax yep thats correct ! just have different unique id for 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem for the submission of the form. These work independently of the id-attribute.

It does however violate some standards, which is further described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59232018) to a related question.